# Flutter - pub get error, when getting versions of path_provider

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm migrating from flutter 1 to flutter 2, and when I updated my packages from pubspec.yaml, I received this error:

> Because path_provider >=1.6.4 <2.0.0-nullsafety depends on path_provider_platform_interface ^1.0.1 which depends on plugin_platform_interface ^1.0.1, path_provider >=1.6.4 <2.0.0-nullsafety requires plugin_platform_interface ^1.0.1.
> And because firebase_messaging >=9.0.0 depends on firebase_core_platform_interface ^4.0.0 which depends on plugin_platform_interface ^2.0.0, path_provider >=1.6.4 <2.0.0-nullsafety is incompatible with firebase_messaging >=9.0.0.
> So, because myApp depends on both firebase_messaging ^9.1.1 and path_provider ^1.6.5, version solving failed.
> Running "flutter pub get" in myApp...
> pub get failed (1; So, because myApp depends on both firebase_messaging ^9.1.1 and path_provider
> ^1.6.5, version solving failed.)

My pubspec.yaml archive:

```
version: 1.0.0+1
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.2.2-dev.68.0 <3.0.0"
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
  path_provider: ^1.6.5

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try out with null safety

```
path_provider:
```

without version.